# Linux Ubuntu won’t Boot Normally

Tags: boot

I shutdown my pc because it was acting real slow, when I went I powered it back on it would enter this other state where it game me booting options. (First Picture) Then when I elected Ubuntu it gave me a message that “/dev/sda5 contains a file system with errors... The root file system on /dev/sda5 requires manual fsck” (Picture 2). Then I clicked help and I got to his message (Picture 3). What can I do to boot Linux normally again? Do I need to reinstall or is there something else I can do?

Pictures aren’t working, but hopefully this is an easy fix, I’ll post the exact code messages later.

Comment: New users aren't allowed to embed links or pictures over a certain number.  Without your pictures we can't help you right now because there's no data.  The error indicates you need to run a file system check on `/dev/sda5` which suggests that you need to boot into a Live USB or installer and run the fsck from there to fix any issues with your disk and filesystem (which happens sometimes)

Comment: It should be possible to do a `fsck -y /dev/sda5` directly at the prompt. Or as @ThomasWard says, boot on USB live media and do it from there if it doesn't work from the prompt.

Comment: Thank you Soren! It works now